# Create an excel formula so that when an input in one sheet auto populated another

Tags: excel

If columns N or O in the Date sheet contain "yes" then the data in that row should auto-populate in a separate sheet.

How do I link the two sheets to perform the operation described above? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need `FILTER()` function.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.